# Air conditioner is hot on one side

Tags: chevrolet, ac, silverado

My 2005 Chevy Silverado with dual zone climate is occasionally blowing hot air on the driver's side and cool on the passenger. It usually works fine for a few minutes before it begins blowing hot air. Once it starts blowing heat, it seems to continue until I park for a while. It doesn't always have this problem.

I'm guessing it's a vacuum or electric problem. I assume that low refrigerant would cause both sides be hot.

Any ideas? I'll probably be taking it to a dealership, but I'd like to know more about the problem before I do that.

Comment: I'm sure it's probably a blend door actuator, but might also be the controller. These are fickle beasts ... I have an '06 Silvy myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common issue. Sometimes the door actuator needs to be reset, as it gets confused. When I had this problem in my Avalanche, I found that turning the temperature all the way to the 90 degree max setting (when set to equal cooling for both sides), waiting a few seconds for the door to stop moving, and then turning the temp back down, would resolve the issue temporarily.

When I took it to the dealer, they said they couldn't find anything wrong with it. After getting tired of dealing with the issue, I tried searching profusely on-line, and eventually found [this page](http://www.justanswer.com/chevy/1e8dl-chevrolet-avalanche-driver-side-cold-air-passenger-side.html) which describes the issue, and a reset procedure to try, which involves removing the fuse. I found this to completely solve the problem for me.

Comment: This is a great answer. You should take the excerpt from the page which describes how to do it and put it on here with a "> " before it, which will quote the text for you. That way if the page should disappear for some reason, the information is still available. Just ensure you reference the page in your write-up as you already have and you're golden.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try it the next time the problem occurs. Should I be able to find a fault code if I have an OBD scanner attached?

Comment: Possibly, but not necessarily. Many scanners will only show powertrain codes, and not body codes. And depending on what is wrong exactly, it may not be setting a code.

Answer (score 2):

On a dual AC 2010 Ford Edge with both thermostats set for AC, the passenger side blew hot air, the driver side cold. I thought at first it may be a faulty blend door actuator on the passenger side. I changed a very dirty cabin filter and started the engine.....immediate cold air blew on the passenger side! Not sure if a dirty cabin filter can confuse the actuator sensor but my system now works perfectly.

Comment: That's interesting. For my Chevy, pulling the fuse fixes the problem when it occurs.